Always Closed Metric Space is Complete
I am trying to prove that

Given a metric space $Y$, if for every metric space $X \supseteq Y$, $Y$ is $X$-closed, then $Y$ is complete.

by contradiction or contraposition, such that I don't use the existence of a completion. (This is 3.3:1 (c) in Bergman's supplementary exercises to Rudin PMA).
Supposing that $Y$ is not complete, I think that the divergent Cauchy sequence in $Y$ should intuitively tend to some $p \not \in Y$. The difficulty, however, is that the ambient space could not be specified until this $p$ is found.
Or could looking at its set of subsequential limits help?

I mean, you can define $X$ as just $Y$ together with $p$, and extend the metric to $X$ such that $d(x,p)$ is just the infimum over each $i$ of the supremum of ${d(x,p_j)}_{j>i}$, where $p_i$ is the cauchy sequence. Clearly $Y$ is not closed in $X$ then.

You should read about Cauchy completion.
